# Question about the words niche & mass

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, antonyms

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter.... ...**Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass.** And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men
>   -----------.

Are "niche" and "mass" nouns here? How am I to understand them? Definitions I found for niche (recess in a wall, private space, habitat, ecological role) and for mass (liturgy, celebration of Eucharist, expanse, bulk, amount of material) do not seem to make sense here. How are these about clothing? Large clothes with much material? Clothes for church? Clothes for habitat? How are these opposites?  ("is not niche. It is mass.)

What words could replace **niche** & **mass** to make this more understandable?

Comment: What do you understand the terms mean? Based on your large volume of questions on this one paragraph, it seems you may not be putting in the effort to figure these out yourself. Can you please explain what you already understand and what it is about these terms that you do not understand?

Comment: Is that just mean suitable? They used the word niche in dictionaries when talking about opportunity to have or sell sth. And it is really confusing when these two words are put against each other, as if mass is something against niche

Comment: They are direct antonyms... I don't think you're reading the definitions correctly or you're using a bad dictionary. "[Niche](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/niche_2) audience" vs "[mass](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mass_2) audience".

Comment: I used longman dictionary

Comment: The important part of those two definitions is the **size** of the audience.

Comment: Oh yes I got them as noun at first

Comment: Oh, yeah, they're adjectives.

Comment: I can see it would be hard to grasp if one doesn't already know the _set phrases_ **niche market** and **mass market**.  It's only in that context that they are antonyms—You cannot readily glean this from the basic definitions of niche and mass.

Comment: Revised question to show some possible confusions from basic noun  definitions of  _niche_  and _mass_. Voting to reopen.

Comment: A funny coincidence that both words can have religious meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Niche (pronounced nitch, rhymes with snitch, but also often niche, rhymes with fiche):  "a shallow recess, especially one in a wall to display a statue or other ornament.  synonyms: recess, alcove, nook, cranny, hollow, bay, cavity, cubbyhole, pigeonhole "a niche in the wall"

From this definition, niche came to mean a tightly defined occupation or lifestyle or position -- e.g., "She found her niche as a translator from Urdu to Norwegian"  (I made up this example.)  Thus a niche market is a small, tightly defined market.  A mass market is a large, broadly defined market.

Comment: If you're going to quote a dictionary, you need to **cite and link to your sources** Also, you've only addressed the niche side and not the mass side.

Answer (score 0):

"Niche market" and "mass market" are two common expressions meaning a narrow market (a particular small category of people) vs. a wide market (almost everybody). The author here is simply making a distinction and the word "market" is implied instead of being stated explicitly.